# Visio : How to change the position of a shape?

Tags: vba, visio

I'd like to change the position X of the object element.CellSRC
Here is the code to set X to 0.1, but I would like to move X from it's position and not just set X to an absolute position.

```
element.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowXFormOut, visXFormPinX).FormulaForceU = "0.1 in"
```

Would you know how to do that ? Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the value in inches and add 0.1 to it:

```
float value = element.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowXFormOut, visXFormPinX).Result["in"] + 0.1;
```

Then set the new value:

```
element.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowXFormOut, visXFormPinX).Result["in"] = value;
```

(I'm not 100% on VBA syntax but thsi shhould get you there)

Answer (score 0):

It worked thanks to Paul Herber's answer, but I just had to modify the 2 lines of code :

```
 Value = element.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowXFormOut, visXFormPinX).result("in") + 0.1
element.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowXFormOut, visXFormPinX).result("in") = Value
```

Comment: Please don't just post code as an answer, but provide an explanation what this does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: you're right but the explanation was the one of Paul Herber and I just modified the syntax to make it work on VBA :) , I could have say it indeed

Comment: I suggest that you edit your answer, to avoid it getting deleted or downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as other answers say, though you'd set the formula or formulaforceu instead of result.
The horrible part of VBA is you have to format it for US decimal representation when setting the formula, or else it will have undesirable behaviors in countries with different decimal representations.  I can't remember. So decimals always have a period decimal separator.

Anyway, you can also use the Selection method, wherein you programmatically select the shape and then call ActiveWindow.Selection.Move x,y